# Use LevelDb with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, leveldb

I wrote in PHP using MySQL. I am trying to write a site using Express & LevelDb.

I need to implement a system of authorization / registration using LevelDb. The only problem is that, I'm new to LevelDb and i didn't found any video tutorials at all.

How to implement system like: {key: username, {values: password, email, etc..}}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**How to implement system like: {key: username, {values: password, email, etc..}}**

Assuming that you already have a working LevelDB database, you could do something like that:

```
var UserInformation = {
    "Email" : NewUserEmailHere,
    "Password" : NewUserPasswordHere,
    "name" : NewUserNameHere 
}

db.put('Username', UserInformation, function(err){
    if (err) return console.log("there was an error", err);
});
```

You can get more information on LevelBD and the put method at this link:
https://github.com/Level/levelup#dbputkey-value-options-callback

You could also use the batch method if you need to execute multiple query:
https://github.com/Level/levelup#dbbatcharray-options-callback-array-form